# Can I Marry more than 1 girl?

Tags: kantai-collection

I read at Level 99 you can marry a Ship Girl which apparently gives them some sort of boost. i am wondering if i can only ever marry 1 girl or can only be wedded to 1 girl or if there is no limit.

Comment: One of these titles again ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can but you need to pay 700 yen per ring to marry more than 1 girl because you have only 1 free ring